# Does Rule Engine Supports NOT IN to check if the element is not present in container or List of Elements in Json Rule Expressions in .Net?

Tags: json, .net, rule-engine

```
{"Rules": [{"Expression": " element NOT IN RestrictedElementList  ", "RuleName": "MyRule", "SuccessEvent": "01"}], "WorkflowName": "MyRule"}
```

Does Rule Engine Support NOT IN? I'm trying to check if the element is present in `RestrictedElementList`.

I tried this

```
{"Rules": [{"Expression": " element NOT IN RestrictedElementList  ", "RuleName": "MyRule", "SuccessEvent": "01"}], "WorkflowName": "MyRule"}
```

and

```
{"Rules": [{"Expression": " !(element IN RestrictedElementList)  ", "RuleName": "MyRule", "SuccessEvent": "01"}], "WorkflowName": "MyRule"}
```

Comment: What rule engine are you talking about? There are a *lot* of rule engine products and libraries in .NET. I bet more than one uses JSON to serialize rules too